how to add to interactive report modal page a column with link to choose a record and send it to parent page?
I'm using oracle apex version 24.1.2. I have a parent page with a button, which opens an interactive grid modal page. In the interactive grid I search for a company and the results are three columns with SAP ID, NAME and ADDRESS. I want to add a 4th column to the results with a link (or button) that will allow user to choose a particular company and return it to parent page with 3 columns SAP ID, NAME and ADDRESS. How can I achieve that?
Thank you
